# Read UTC timestamp from questdb with pg module. Date object has wrong UTC time

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone, questdb

All the timestamps in the questdb are UTC times but when I read them with the [nodejs questdb client](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/query-data/#postgresql-wire-protocol) it will give me the correct time but with my local timezone.

For example, in the database a time of 10:00 UTC is stored and when reading this time in nodejs I will get 10:00 GMT+0200 (So 8:00 UTC).

How can I read that time as UTC/GMT+0200 so I get a correct Date object?

This is my current code to read out the data from questdb:

```
  async getData(unitId: string) {
    const client = new Client([...]);
    await client.connect();
    const res = await client.query(
      `select Timestamp from 'myData' where ...`,
    );
    await client.end();
    return res.rows.map((x) => x?.Timestamp); // Timestamp is already an Date object with 10:00 GMT+0200
  }
```

Edit:

To make it more clear what my problem is:

The database contains the date `2023-09-26T06:18:56.740000Z`. I just saved that entry at 8:18 local time and since I am located in GMT+0200 this is the right UTC time.
[image]

Now when I want to get this entry from the database with the code snipped above, I will get a date like the timestamp entry was read as local time. Meaning it will take the 06:18 and applies the GMT+0200 to it to make it 06:18 GMT+0200. When doing `Timestamp.toISOString()` I will get `2023-09-26T04:18:56.740Z`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you're referring to uses `pg` library, so you should check its documentation and, namely, the data type page: https://node-postgres.com/features/types

The documentation mentions the following:

> Likewise, when reading a `date`, `timestamp`, or `timestamptz` column value back into JavaScript, node-postgres will parse the value into an instance of a JavaScript Date object.

> node-postgres converts `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` columns into the local time of the node process set at `process.env.TZ`.

So, that's why you're getting a `Date` with a local timezone instead of UTC.

If you don't want to mess with the environment variable, you can define a custom parser for the `timestamp` type. Please, check examples in https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types for more detail.

P.S. The underlying reason is that Postgres assumes that `timestamp` time doesn't have a timezone while in QuestDB it always has the UTC timezone. We'll try fixing that in future.

Comment: It's not bad that the timezone is initialized, its bad that the time itself is wrong because of that. 10:00 UTC is not the same as 10:00 GMT+0200. If I would set my timezone to UTC or convert to it, I would just get 08:00 and thats wrong.

Comment: Makes sense. Then you should set `process.env.TZ` to tell `pg` which timezone to use.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't apply here.  JS `Date` objects don't encapsulate any time zone information themselves.  They are UTC based - _always_.  They only use the time zones when certain functions are called.

Comment: Yes, my above reply is not correct in the "initialized timezone" and Date conversion parts. I'll correct the text. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `Date` objects are *always* UTC only.  They are a simple wrapper around a Unix timestamp with milliseconds precision.  You can see that timestamp with `.valueOf()`, or `.getTime()` or by coercing it to a number type (i.e. `+d`).

If your database is returning UTC times in JS `Date` objects, then it is doing the correct thing already.

The code you showed returns `Date` objects, but you didn't show how you are *using* those objects.  Likely you are viewing the result of coercing the `Date` object to a string for display.  For example, a call to `.toString()` will use the computer's local time zone to convert the UTC-based timestamp to local time, then emit a string representing local time.  By contrast, a call to `.toISOString()` or `.toUTCString()` will emit a string representing the UTC time without any conversion.

Worth noting here (as is often a trap) - if you `console.log(someDateObject)` - the resulting string might be *either* local time or UTC time depending on environment.  Neither the ECMAScript spec, nor the WhatWG Console spec define which it should be, and different JavaScript implementations have chosen differently over the years.  Instead of logging the `Date` object, log the string output of one of the functions on the `Date` object - such as `.toISOString()` if you want UTC.

Comment: The database contains the date `2023-09-26T06:18:56.740000Z` and when I do `Timestamp.toISOString()` in the code snipped I get `2023-09-26T04:18:56.740Z`. Maybe with that it is more clearly what my problem is.

Comment: It sounds like there were two things at play.  The first being what I called out in this answer.  The second being closer to Andrei's answer - You likely need to set `process.env.TZ` to `"UTC"`.  Or try setting `TZ=UTC` environment variable when launching Node.js.

Comment: Also, I know nothing about QuestDB, but if it is supporting PostgreSQL syntax, you could try `SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'` as part of your SQL query, before the `SELECT` statment.

Answer (score -1):

A quick workaround that I currently have is just to add the timezone again to the Date:

```
return res.rows?.map((x) => {
      x?.Timestamp.setTime(
        x.Timestamp.getTime() +
          x.Timestamp.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 * -1,
      );
      return x.Timestamp;
    });
```

Comment: You should not do this.  You may think that you are adjusting for the time zone offset, but actually you are moving the UTC point in time represented by the `Date` object to a different point in time.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint That's exactly what I want to do. Like I said, it read's the UTC time from the DB as local time so the UTC time of the Date object is missaligned by the time zone.

Comment: Yeah, but even with that, you'll still hit edge cases near DST transitions, where the offset returned by `getTimezoneOffset` is not correct for the timestamp you're adjusting.  Better to fix the problem at the source, than correcting for it like this.